# OpenX( open-source-ad-server ) suitable version

Tags: openx, advertisement-server

There are mostly two versions of openX server available to download

http://www.openx.org/publisher/open-source-ad-server

- Publisher server
- Advertisers server

We want to setup local OpenX server and we will use java app to add adds in Openx server following this guideline anybody recommend which server we need ? and which one is easy and flexible to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one software to download, and it allows management of both advertisers and publishers.

OpenX-download runs on LAMP; and a complete set of system requirements are noted [here](http://www.openx.org/docs/2.8/adminguide/System+requirements).

If you are using java, then you can use the [APIs](https://developer.openx.org/wiki/display/API/Home) available to create campaigns, banners, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should take into consideration the fact that not everything is exposed through the Java API, and sometimes you'll have to dig into OpenX code in order to fix bugs. Not a showstopper, but you should add that into your planning.